# Nifi Controller Service What is the difference between JsontreeReader and JsonPath reader

Tags: json, string, parsing, apache-nifi, processor

I have a simple question. What is the difference between JsontreeReader and JsonPath reader?
I am new to NiFi. I am trying to parse a string. I have another open question that no one seems to want to answer. For a example!
[Nifi JOLT Transform string delimited into different elements and subelements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421111/nifi-jolt-transform-string-delimited-into-different-elements-and-subelements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JsonTreeReader reads the entire JSON as a record, or in the case of a top-level array, each element in the array is read (entirely) as a record. JsonPathReader lets you specify JSONPath expressions in order to get at particular objects/records/fields within the overall flow file.